# Proxy Caching with Vary Query Params

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, konga

I am trying to configure caching in KONGA for certain URL with query params.

What I would like to achieve is :

This should be cached -> `GET /my-awesome-service/get-something?filter-one=this&filter-two=that`

This should be cached differently -> `GET /my-awesome-service/get-something?filter-one=this&filter-two=their`

What I am facing is `GET /my-awesome-service/get-something` is being cached and hence returning incorrect data for different filters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As explain [into the documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/proxy-cache/#parameters) you need to set the query param to use on the cache key via `config.vary_query_params` or keep it undefined to use all query params.
You already set it to `timeframe` so you need to add `filter-one` and `filter-two`

Yaml should be something like that:

```
        plugins:
          - name: proxy-cache
            config:
              cache_control: false
              content_type:
                - application/json
              memory:
                dictionary_name: kong_db_cache
              request_method:
                - GET
              response_code:
                - 200
              strategy: memory
              vary_query_params:
                - timeframe
                - filter-one
                - filter-two
            enabled: true
            protocols:
              - grpc
              - grpcs
              - http
              - https
```